# How to make firefox extension run js on specified domain

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I had made a Chrome extension in past, which runs only on a domain (say `test.com`), and executes my JS file (say `my.js`) as soon as that domain is opened. I wish to port it to Firefox.

How can this be done? I am new to Firefox add-on development. I tried reading from Firefox docs but was unable to understand.

Comment: Do you mean you want to run JS on any page loaded from a specific host? Greasemonkey scripts are good for that. In extensions, I am not sure, but I guess you have to somehow listen to changes of tabs’ location and execute your JS code conditionally from the handler.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a bootstrapped addon or Overlay addon?

Anyway .... try the code given on [On page load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/On_page_load)

```
var myExtension = {
    init: function() {
        // The event can be DOMContentLoaded, pageshow, pagehide, load or unload.
        if(gBrowser) gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", this.onPageLoad, false);
    },
    onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {
        var doc = aEvent.originalTarget; // doc is document that triggered the event
        var win = doc.defaultView; // win is the window for the doc
        // test desired conditions and do something
        // if (doc.nodeName != "#document") return; // only documents
        // if (win != win.top) return; //only top window.
        // if (win.frameElement) return; // skip iframes/frames
        alert("page is loaded \n" +doc.location.href);
    }
}
window.addEventListener("load", function load(event){
    window.removeEventListener("load", load, false); //remove listener, no longer needed
    myExtension.init();  
},false);
```

What I have done myself is (for example running on imdb.com only):

```
let doc = aEvent.originalTarget;
if (doc.location.hostname.match(/\.imdb\.com$/)) {
    // this is the page that you want to run on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Addon-SDK with Firefox, you'll pretty much just need the [page-mod module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod), which executes a script anytime the domain/URL matches what the page-mod expects. Check that out, and also about how content-scripts communicate with an addon.